# Android, communicating with two instances of an application via GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'll start with the project idea I have in hand:

> We are trying to make a simple application that requires the sending of messages between phones. Say there's phone A and phone B, and both have installed the application. Phone A sends a message to B through the application, and B receives it. B can do the same and send messages to phone A.

Since we want to target from Gingerbread and up, [Wifip2p](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/package-summary.html) from google is not possible since it requires API 14 and up.

I read about [GCM](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html) , and while I do understand the concept there's something I don't quite get yet. Every instance of the application registers with the server, the server then saves the ID so it can later use it to communicate to the GCM, and the GCM can use the registration ID to deliver the message to the phone.

**What I don't understand is how phone A will be able to know the ID that corresponds to phone B, in order to tell the server to deliver the message to phone B.**

I'd really appreciate the help, thanks.

**EDITTED**

Based no the answers, I think I'm not managing to express my question properly.

I understand that this systems bases itself in three factors: a server, GCM, and your device.

The device registers with the server, and the servers saves the device's registration ID which it will, later on, use to send it to the GCM so that the GCM can then send the appropriate message to the device.

> What I don't understand is how the following procedure is carried out:

PhoneA wants to send a message to PhoneB, so phoneA would send this message to the Server, and the Server would later pass it on to the GCM who would then pass it on to phone B.

This explanation is nice, in the abstract vision of it all. But, **how does phoneA tell the server that it wants the message delivered to phoneB. How does phoneA even know what ID corresponds to phoneB?**

Hopefully this clears it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone A doesn't need to know the ID of phone B. Just make a method in your server that delivers a list of clients you are interested in (phone B, C, D, etc) when you connect.

When you send a message to your server, include the handle of the phone you want to deliver to. This should not be the other phone's GCM registration ID in my opinion, but rather a unique handle generated by the server.

For this to work, you need to either implement a `your server -> phone A` communication or use GCM to deliver the list of clients as a notification.

Comment: One other question, when the device registers on the server, can the device itself pass its own "handle" for the server to save?

Comment: @Joy I would let the server assign a handle while registering. If devices generate their handle you might run into problems with duplicate handles. Using e.g. an email address as handle works as well but you need to add something that handles the "handle already taken" case.

Comment: @zapl Beat me to it, I was just editing my post with the exact same remark. Nevertheless, considering that you implement both the client and the server yourself, nothing stops you from passing whatever data you want from your client to your server.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to see someone actually accepting a high-level approach instead of parroting "give me code examples, do my job for me for free".